# Use layout editor effectively on layouts with non-static fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic, android-context, graphical-layout-editor

With all the Android development tools greatness, especially as of version 21, the graphical layout editor is a powerful tool to have visual control over a layout with fragments for every configuration and locale. I'm aware that a typical `Activity`'s layout XML will contain static `fragment` tags with info embedded for the layout editor, for example `tools:layout="@layout/book_collection_view_window_list"`.

However, because I need to replace the `Fragments` in my window dynamically, I cannot use the static `fragment` tags, and instead need to provide containers, such as `FrameLayout`, to which I can refer in `replace()`. Is there something like `tools:layout` or `tools:context` I can use on this container so in the layout editor there is more than just black emptyness, and so I can leverage the design and verification features it would give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android%3aforeground) for `FrameLayout`, like there is an attribute you can use on the `FrameLayout` tag to put a drawable in the foreground of the ViewGroup.

You could use this to see the FrameLayout whilst you are setting up your view.  I often just put a colour in so I can see where it is relative to the background and other `View`s.

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, but it's a start. Since you seem to be using it already, could you include a line of code? Any thoughts on how to only show it in the tool and not when running (maybe make a custom view and do it programmatically?)?

Comment: I would use XML such as `android:background="#FF0000"` for red. If your `Fragment`s are opaque, you don't need to do anything to hide the red colour, but I would remove it from your XML once you've laid everything out. Alternatively, you can set the background of the `FrameLayout` at runtime when you add the `Fragment` using the `FragmentManager` by using code such as: `findViewById(R.id.frame_layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: Another solution is to sub class the `FrameLayout` and do something like override the `addChild()` methods and clear the background colour before calling `super()`.  Or, if it's possible to identify in the constructor that the layout was instantiated by the tool, then set a random colour to the background programatically.  It all seems overkill when you can just remove the colour after setting up your XML though.