# Show a Fragment in FrameLayout without <fragment> element in layout editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, graphical-layout-editor

I know that `tools:layout` can be used to show a fragment in `<fragment>` elements in the *Android Studio's layout editor*.

However, I want to add a fragment in a FrameLayout *at runtime* (so that I can change the fragment).

Similar questions found in SO like [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882159/layout-editor-how-to-show-layout-in-framelayout-container) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675456/use-layout-editor-effectively-on-layouts-with-non-static-fragments), but the answers in the pages cannot solve the problem exactly.

What I want to do is:

- In an activity layout XML file

  - Insert a fragment (or fragment's layout XML) in a FrameLayout **in the layout editor**, without any `<fragment>` or `<include>` elements.
- Something like `tools:layout` but not using `<fragment>` because it is not changeable. It is possible to use something like `View.isInEditMode` in code)

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: @mfekim Not yet.